# How do I combine my Equipment?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

The game tells me that I can Combine multiples of the same item to make them more powerful. Cool! I have a few doubles, and I'd like to try it out!

So, I go to the Inventory Screen, select "Combine Items", and...

[image: Combine Items Screen]

Everything is greyed out with a big pink **LOW LV** on the top left. Tapping on the various items does nothing.

What am I missing? How can I combine these items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade the equipment to its (current) max level before you can combine them with other items of the same type to increase the max level.

Upgrading also requires sacrifice of acquired equipment, but it doesn't have to be of the same type.

Comment: I would post a screenshot, but as I did this before seeing your question I don't have anything valid atm either.

Comment: Well that's not particularly intuitive. (But yeah, it works. Also, you can upgrade equipment using the upgrade stone things much more efficiently than using other gear.)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz hah, thanks! I keep missing things like that. The little pop ups with information aren't terr clear in a lot of cases, I think.

Comment: One thing to note: only the item that you want to have an increased rarity has to be at max level. For example, if you have two 1* Broadswords, you only need to upgrade one of them to 3/3 and then you can combine the 3/3 item with the 1/3 item to create a 3/5 2* Broadsword+. I wasn't aware of this at the start and wasted some items upgrading both to 3/3 before combining.

Comment: @Tom sorry that wasn't clear. I can't edit just now but will try to clarify / expand this answer tonight when I should be able to incorporate some screenshots.

Comment: No worries, just wanted to throw it out there so anyone reading this question/answer doesn't have to waste equipment/Gil like I did :)